# Failed to build libwebrtc.aar with latest native webrtc android code

Tags: android, webrtc

When running build_aar.py for libwebrtc android, i got this error:

ERROR at //build/config/BUILDCONFIG.gn:564:5: Dependency not allowed.
    target(_target_type, target_name) {
    ^----------------------------------
The item //rtc_tools:psnr_ssim_analyzer
can not depend on //third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/flags:usage
because it is not in //third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/flags:usage's visibility list: [
  //third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/flags:*
]

Can any one help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly did not sync the project with his dependencies.
`gclient sync` or `gclient sync -D --force --reset` if needed.
See [chromium doc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/building_old_revisions.md).